# The amb -< operator is not defined

Tags: racket

I see this in the lecture slide

```
> (+ 10 (-< 1 2 3))
11
> (next)
12
> (next)
13
> (next)
'done
```

But when I tried it my own in DrRacket, it came up with an error

```
> (+ 10 (-< 1 2 3))
. . -<: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
>
```

The slide didn't indicate any requirement. I also google "racket -<: undefined", but seems google can't find any result relate to the symbol -<. How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you're going to have to tell us *whose lecture* :). It looks like the amb operator that your instructor is using creates a re-entrant generator using continuations, but to tell you more, you'll have to give us more details. Put differently: it isn't hard to implement something like what you've described, but AFAICT, it's not part of a standard built-in library.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see ur comment. Here is the lecture 
 slide.  https://mcs.utm.utoronto.ca/~324/lec/lec07/slides07.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the link to the slides that you posted, it appears that the `-<` form is defined as a macro (using syntax-rules) on slide 19/48. After you add that macro definition to your program, you should be able to use the `-<` form.